# SQL query'ish for what I want to achieve in Pouchdb

Tags: sql, pouchdb, nosql

```
SELECT * FROM smo_images
WHERE search_term in search_helpers (search helpers is array or keywords)
OR search_term = smo_code
OR search_term = size
OR search_term = category;
```

I would like to achieve something like above in PouchDB. I am new to nosql and PouchDB. The documentation is confusing and not straightforward.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, [the documentation](https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html) is quite clear and straightforward. It mentions the old-school method of SQL:

> **Indexes in SQL databases**
>
> Quick refresher on how indexes work: in
>   relational databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL, you can usually query
>   whatever field you want:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name = 'Pikachu';
> ```
>
> But if you don't want your performance to be terrible, you first add
>   an index:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE pokemon ADD INDEX myIndex ON (name);
> ```
>
> The job of the index is to ensure the field is stored in a B-tree
>   within the database, so your queries run in O(log(n)) time instead of
>   O(n) time.

From there, it starts a comparison with NoSQL:

> **Indexes in NoSQL databases**
>
> All of the above is also true in document stores like CouchDB and
>   MongoDB, but conceptually it's a little different. By default,
>   documents are assumed to be schemaless blobs with one primary key
>   (called _id in both Mongo and Couch), and any other keys need to be
>   specified separately. The concepts are largely the same; it's mostly
>   just the vocabulary that's different.
>
> In CouchDB, queries are called map/reduce functions. This is because,
>   like most NoSQL databases, CouchDB is designed to scale well across
>   multiple computers, and to perform efficient query operations in
>   parallel. Basically, the idea is that you divide your query into a map
>   function and a reduce function, each of which may be executed in
>   parallel in a multi-node cluster.

It continues with descriptions and sample codes on Map/Reduce functions, temporary/persistent views and many more.